# May I wish all on Christianity SE a Blessed and Holy Easter Sunday (2022)?

Tags: discussion

May I wish all on Christianity SE a Blessed and Holy Easter Sunday (April 17, 2022)!

May all of you enjoy the fruits of a blessed [***Resurrection Sunday***](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/90516/when-and-by-whom-did-what-we-now-call-easter-sunday-first-become-known-as-resu). Especially, those who are suffering in some form or another, especially those who are in war situations as in the Ukraine.

For those you it may interest I would like to mention that there will be a [Parade of Planets Will Cross the Night Sky Through Spring 2022](https://petapixel.com/2022/03/25/a-parade-of-planets-will-cross-the-night-sky-through-spring-2022/)

> By mid-April, Jupiter will make an appearance. Technically, it’s visible starting as early as April 17, but the viewing experience will get better as the latter days of the month approach.
>
> [image]
>
> By April 23, the Moon makes an appearance. As mentioned, it might be difficult to see Neptune amongst the stars and the other planets in this alignment, but it will also be there just to the right of Jupiter for those who wish to catch a glimpse. The alignment below will take place from the perspective of those in Los Angeles at 5:25 AM.
>
> [image]

The Planet Alignment Key Dates:

- April 17: Alignment starts to form
- April 20: Alignment is most visible
- April 23: Moon lines up too
- April 29: Moon gets too close to the sun to be visible

However you celebrate Easter, you may wish to look to the heavens and enjoy your exceptional heavenly display God has given us.

Any other ideas for Easter Sunday 2022?

Happy Easter everyone!

Comment: Happy Holy Week to you Ken, along with everyone else on C.SE!

Comment: I wish all a deepening faith resulting from reflection of what Jesus has done for us in this Holy Week.  I'm counting down to [Easter 2033](https://www.jc2033.world/), the 2000th anniversary of Resurrection.

Answer (score 2):

Trust me to find your post too late - story of my life!  But thank you for your kind message and for the information about the 'Parade of Planets' in April.

At church on Sunday we were praying for the people of Ukraine, conscious that at the start of the invasion the Patriarch of Moscow praised President Putin's "high and responsible service to the people".  I believe that the Eastern Orthodox Church celebrates Easter this coming week.

All I can say is "May God's will be done on earth, as it is done in heaven, and may God's kingdom come" soon.

Comment: Yes, when I saw this post I thought, "well, perhaps not _all_ on Christianity SE" ;)

Comment: @Alex, ah, quite so. :)